# HttpClient examples with HttpResponse

Tags: java, httpclient, httpresponse

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
//...
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(url);
```

I use the following external libraries:

- httpclient-4.1.2
- commons-codec-1.4
- commons-logging-1.1.1

In all HttpClient examples from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) they use the HttpResponse but I can't find any class to import for the HttpResponse. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpResponse` lives in [`HttpCore` (docs)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html).

They're both part of [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

HttpResponse resides in org.apache.http package.

It's mentioned at the top of the [HttpResponse javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html)

edit:

you need httpcore-4.1.2.jar to import it.

Answer (score 0):

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327267/15155030), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated